# Which of Jabba’s Gamorreans swore fealty to Boba Fett?

Tags: star-wars, the-book-of-boba-fett

The two gamorreans who were spared by Boba in exchange for their service were described as having served Jabba then Fortuna.

[image]

Ten of Jabba’s guards were named in various expanded universe works:

- Gartogg - protagonist of “And Then There Were Some: The Gamorrean Guard's Tale”
- Ghana Gleemort (Decipher CCG)
- Grissom (Dark Horse Comics *Star Wars Tales #3*, “Three Against the Galaxy”)
- Jubnuk - the Gamorrean who fell into the Rancor pit with Luke Skywalker (*Jabba’s Palace Pop-up Book*)
- Ortugg - captain of the guards (WEG *Rebellion Era Sourcebook*)
- Rogua - often partnered with Ortugg (“And Then There We’re Some: The Gamorrean Guard’s Tale”)
- Scumbo - had a history with Thok https://web.archive.org/web/20170129091354/https://www.starwars.com/news/barely-tolerable-alien-henchmen-of-the-empire-part-2
- Thok - often partnered with Thug https://web.archive.org/web/20170129091354/https://www.starwars.com/news/barely-tolerable-alien-henchmen-of-the-empire-part-2
- Thug - often partnered with Thok https://web.archive.org/web/20170129091354/https://www.starwars.com/news/barely-tolerable-alien-henchmen-of-the-empire-part-2
- Warlug - guard who remained behind at Jabba's palace rather than accompany him to the Pit of Carkoon (“Skin Deep: The Fat Dancer's Tale”)

Another thirteen were named in *Star Wars: Galaxies:*

- Agtor
- Artogg
- Drognuz
- Grogur
- Gurgot
- Ogtur
- Rautog
- Torgau
- Torrug
- Ugtaur
- Urgott

Were these two Gamorreans any of these existing Gamorreans?

Comment: Did they even *try* to make them look right?  Wrong number of tushes, no curve to their horns, nostrils upside-down...

Comment: Well, I wasn’t counting tushes. 

Comment: @Buzz Could be an age thing. I'll have to rewatch the episode later, but the above screenshot might be have a hint of the second pair of tusks coming in. Maybe Boba's guards are just youngsters.

Comment: @Harabeck I suppose generational servitude might be possibility, but it was my impression that these two were intended to have served Jabba, chosen to serve Fortuna, and then Fett appeals to continue same for him. I accept possibility that Jabba may have had more than 23 guards, and these may have been guards not yet named, but what’s a rare condition that would be in face of WEG, decipher, and the other EU of the golden EU era 80s-00’s naming and detailing everything under the sun.

Comment: Yeah, supposedly their full lifetime is 45. Maybe they were hired right as Jabba died or something? Still not sure if that lines up.